# Monotouch.Dialog StyledStringElement full image

Tags: iphone, xamarin.ios, xamarin, monotouch.dialog

(iPhone and iPad)

My designer wishes to use her own image as a button where currently a StyledStringElement is.

Can the StyledStringElement have the normal and tapped state image of itself be completely the only thing seen? Ideally I'd like to provide something like the 9 Patches that Android uses otherwise I'd provide the complete image of itself.